# Unresolved external SHCreateItemFromParsingName referenced VCL.LIB / Dialogs on C++Builder XE8

Tags: vcl, c++builder-xe8

I have a application of C++Builder6, and I'm migrating it to C++BuilderXE8 via C++Builder2007 on Windows7.
I compiled with success on C++Builder2007.
But I have a error on C++BuilderXE8:

> [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external
>   'SHCreateItemFromParsingName' referenced from C:\PROGRAM
>   FILES\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\16.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\VCL.LIB|Vcl.Dialogs

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unresolved external SHCreateItemFromParsingName referenced VCL.LIB / Dialogs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403887/unresolved-external-shcreateitemfromparsingname-referenced-vcl-lib-dialogs)

Answer (score 1):

One solution - if you do not use VCL - is to edit the project file and remove all vcl.lib imports.

Answer (score 0):

`SHCreateItemFromParsingName()` is exported from `SHELL32.DLL`.  Make sure you have added `SHELL32.LIB` (32bit) or `SHELL32.A` (64bit) to your project.  You can find them in the following folders of your IDE installation:

```
$(BDS)\lib\win32\release\psdk
$(BDS)\lib\win64\release\psdk
```

You can either add the actual .lib/.a file to your project, or you can use a `#pragma comment(lib)` statement in your C++ code.

Comment: I add 'shell32.lib' in the folder of IDE installation to my project, but I still have same error.
 How do I resolve this problem?